# Combining heterogeneous recursive types in order to define a sublanguage

Tags: c++11, recursion, types

I am trying to define a basic language to build expressions which I will evaluate myself from code. Such expressions are defined recursively in run time. You may think of it as boolean expressions having elementary expressions like True and False, and also involving complex expressions like the negation of an expression and the disjunction and conjunction of any two expressions.

As mentioned, such expressions are recursive and will be created in run time, so I guess templates are no choice. What is the most suitable way to implement typing and an evaluation function in C++ 2011 for this purpose?

Any comments will be welcome, as my knownledge on C++ patterns and features sadly does not get quite far yet.

Sample nonworking code, which illustrates the fact that I'm not needing any external representation for expressions (as strings):

```
struct basic {
    bool val;
};
struct complex_neg {
    expression exp;
};
struct complex_and {
    expression exp1, exp2;
};
struct expression : basic, complex_neg, complex_and {
    bool eval() {
        if (dynamic_cast<basic*>(this)) return this->val;
        else if (dynamic_cast<complex_neg*>(this)) return !this->eval();
        else return this->eval() && this->eval();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your early replies. I forgot to mention that using third party libraries is not a option I can afford, as the code will be targeted for a mobile phone app.

Comment: Note that header-only libraries (such as Boost.Spirit mentioned below) are not a problem, since they have no binary file you'd have to provide to the user.

Comment: Thank you, but I still believe my problem is much simpler and should no require any external library. I have added further information to make my question more verbose.

Comment: `expression` inheriting from `basic`, `complex_neg`, and `complex_and` means that it is a composition of these three classes, not just one of them. Hence, the first `dynamic_cast` will always pass.

Comment: thank you. how can i express it is either one of them?

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to build a tree / directed graph of your expressions and terminals. See [Abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

And then evaluate that expression tree.

In C++, one of the most convenient ways to build an AST so is to use [Boost Spirit, see a good introduction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html#spirit.introduction.a_quick_overview_of_parsing_with__emphasis_spirit_qi__emphasis_).

Comment: Thanks. I am acknownledge with basic data structures, but so far have no clue how to implement it the simplest way possible in C++.

Comment: @jvier Reading spirit documentation will make things much clearer for you. There is no shortcut, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The most primitive thing you could try is [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) with inverse polish notation.

The most professional thing you can do is to use [boost spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)

The most bad-ass you can do is implement yourself an ll parser for your specific grammar. But you need to know some theory about language parsers.

Comment: Thank you. The grammar I am needing does not apply to user readable representations like strings. My question relates to how C++ typing and other features can be used to define such a recursive syntax (i.e., class inheritance).

Comment: @jvier It is very unclear what you mean. Are you talking about expression templates?

Comment: That could be indeed a choice. I will add some code to illustrate.